# Insert XML node in treeveiw

Tags: c#, xml, treeview, nodes, xmldocument

I am trying to add a ChildNode to an already existent Node, both in treeview and internally using XmlDocument.
Firstly, I find the parent node (P) and I attach one child (N) to it. Then I replace the original child node (P) with the new node (P+N). However, I noticed that even tho I do not get any errors, the child count of the parent P remains constant, even after adding a new child. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
        XmlNode parentNode = fh.findNode(xmlFile.DocumentElement.ChildNodes, selectedTreeNode);
        XmlNode initialNode = parentNode;
        foreach (XmlNode node in parentNode.ChildNodes)
        {   
           if (node.Name == this.lbElements.SelectedItem.ToString())
           {
                parentNode.InsertAfter(node, node);
                this.xmlFile.DocumentElement.ReplaceChild(initialNode, parentNode);
                this.rtbText.Text = textIndentation(xmlFile);
                treeView1.Invalidate();
                break;
           }
       }
```

Comment: Take a look at parentNode.InsertAfter(node, node); You need to save the return value of this function: this is the node being inserted! And (node, node) seems to be wrong: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.insertafter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yeah i noticed that it actually just replaces the original child with the new one. Since they are the same, nothing (visibly) changes.